# Wait until alert is present in Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I have an excel macro that enters data into a web-form (usng selenium and web driver). After each submission (by clicking submit button), a popup appears and the macro clicks OK on that alert by running this code line`obj.SwitchToAlert.accept` to continue the loop . Entire code is working fine. Only problem is sometimes the  alert takes 5-10 seconds to appear. That time the code proceeds to click the button and gives error (as no alert pop up is present yet).

Is there any way that macro can wait until the alert is present before running `obj.SwitchToAlert.accept`?

Comment: Use Application.Wait?

Comment: @Skin there is no busy/load sign in Chrome. Otherwise I would have used it. Usually the popup appears instantly in less than a second. I want the code to verify if the alert has popped up and only then proceed to clicking on that alert. will any loop work?

Comment: You are partially correct that there is no `Busy` property as there is with `InternetExplorerObj.Busy`. Fortunately, the ChromeDriver handles this better, within the method itself. Most of your methods and functions, such as `FindElementBy...()` have an optional `Timeout` argument. This is essentially now your `IE.Busy` property, but implemented in a much better way.

Comment: Is there a public url we can use to reproduce this? You have a great answer from @K.Dᴀᴠɪs (+) - but I would like to see what else might be possible.

Comment: @QHarr Unfortunatley, I don't have any public url. The Url we are using is on intranet. the code K.Davis has suggested ```obj.SwitchToAlert(20).accept``` is not working at all. Its throwing 'Run-Time error 27' NoAlertPresentError no such alert' everytime. When using time!

Answer (score 1):

There are additional parameters in the `SwitchToAlert` method that you have overlooked.

The one in particular is the `Optional Timeout As long = -1` parameter. Set this to a value, such as 20. This means it will wait *a maximum time of* 20 seconds for your alert to appear, then click accept. If it appears in 5 seconds, you only wait 5 seconds (not the full 20).

```
obj.SwitchToAlert(20).accept
```

Would be the line you are wanting to use.

When you are using the default value of `-1`, you are telling this method to use the global default timeout, which is 5 seconds. You can change this global value by changing the `obj.Timeouts.ImplicitWait` property.

Comment: @K.Davis ```obj.SwitchToAlert(20).accept``` is throwing me to my error handler. Is the correct property? or it should be ```obj.SwitchToAlert(20 = -1).accept```?

Comment: @K.Davis Maybe the error is caused because I am closing the alert myself (in debug mode) to check if your suggestion is working! I do not have another way to test it since, the error earlier appeared randomly. I'll test it on my macro for next couple of days to check if the error re-appears. I'll mark it as an answer then. Hope that'll be OK for you.

Comment: No rush @PrateekVishwas. Let me know if you need additional assistance.

Comment: Hello @K.Davis, I distributed the macro among my team members with wait time parameters in that line i.e. ```obj.SwitchToAlert(20).accept```. However, they still encountered errors at random times. Just when this line should have been executed. They did not take any screenshots though of that error. Can we create a loop to check if the alert is present before the code tries to click on the accept button? I tried ```AlertChecker:
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
If verifyAlertPresent = False Then
    GoTo AlertChecker
End If``` But didn't work!!

Comment: It's stuck in endless loop. If I change the value to True, then it simply jumps to accept the alert code even if the alert is not present.

Comment: Hey @K.Davis, I've just received an screenshot of the error! It's 'Run-Time error 27' NoAlertPresentError no such alert